# Grabbing enough M&Ms to be 80% confident all colors are represented

Tags: probability

Assume you have an arbitrarily large jar of M&Ms, with six different colors of M&Ms present in equal quantities. If you reach into the jar and grab a fistful (what we'll call a "pull" from now on), sometimes you'll get all colors represented, and sometimes you won't. The probability that all colors will be represented is clearly a color of how large your pull is.

What is the smallest sized pull that would give you an 80% confidence that you'll have at least one of each color?

[image: Arbitrarily large jar of M&Ms]

Comment: That's a math problem.

Comment: @FlorianF I'm not sure I understand where the line is between a puzzle and a fun math problem? When I worked this out myself* prior to posting it, I got the same answer as below, but I couldn't find a closed-form solution, so I was curious if someone else would. Alas, the answer I accepted also didn't provide a closed-form solution. (*I did a wee bit of hand-waving instead of using code, but got the same result, based on sequence A000770 - OEIS.)

Comment: @FlorianF. sadly, because this has been closed, I cannot post the analysis I had done previously as an answer (I wanted to wait until someone else had a chance to answer), which I think would be kind of fun because it shows a very different way of getting the same result.

Comment: I feel sorry.  My first reaction was to say it is a maths problem.  But on the other hand, other problems like the "birthday paradox" have been posted here.  And it was OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, given a draw of $c$ different colours, the odds of the next M&M drawn being of a new colour is $\frac{6 - c}{6}$. So we can figure this out iteratively - you could code this, or do what I did and use a big ol' spreadsheet:

[image: fig 1: big ol' spreadsheet]

We can see that the first time P(6 colours) exceeds 0.8 is at 19 M&Ms.

If you're after a more analytical solution: the number of different ways to pull $n$ M&Ms is $6^n$. The number of ways to pull $n$ M&Ms of at most five colours is a little under $6 \times 5^n.$ (A little under because we're double-counting cases where 4 or fewer colours are represented). So, we want:

$\frac{6 * 5^n}{6^{n}} \le \frac{1}{5}$
$\implies (\frac{5}{6})^n \le \frac{1}{30}$
$\implies \ln((\frac{5}{6})^n) \le \ln(\frac{1}{30})$
$\implies n \ge \frac{\ln(\frac{1}{30})}{\ln(\frac{5}{6})}$ *(as $\ln(\frac{5}{6})$ is negative)*
$\implies n \ge 18.65$

This suggests that $n = 19$, which matches our earlier work. Were this our only calculation, we would then need to check that 18 did not work (as we over-counted our 5-colour draws, so the crossing point is less than 18.65) - this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I just made the exact same spreadsheet, but without the colors.  Same values, same result.

Comment: Via the inclusion-exclusion principle, the exact probability for a pull of size $n$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^6 (-1)^k \binom{6}{k}(1-k/6)^n,$$ which is indeed $<0.8$ for $n=18$ and $>0.8$ for $n=19$.

Comment: Very nice! I got the same answer, using a very different result (my solution relied on sequence A000770 - OEIS).  @RobPratt, when I have a chance to think about your solution more, I'd probably understand why sequence A000770 - OEIS works. My exact solution was (sequence A000770 - OEIS) / 6^(n-6) * 6!/6^6, where n is the side of the pull. My way of "figuring it out" was very imprecise, though. I considered all of the cases for n=6, 7, and 8, and realized that the terms in the formula above were 1, 21, and 266, then went hunting for a sequence beginning with these three terms. Very sloppy!